# Androidplot - Not displayed in landscape

Tags: android, androidplot

If I plot a bar chart using Androidplot and then change my phones orientation from portrait to landscape all the chart information disappears. (link to screenshots).

Landscape --- no chart data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4CxFPSlLEYpSXV1VnZFVFUtWGc/edit?usp=sharing

Portrait --- chart data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4CxFPSlLEYpdGZCMm8xdGZHTlk/edit?usp=sharing

After some trial and error I found that if I set the chart width to be 0.96 of the devices screen width all the chart information appeared again.

How can I get Androidplot to take up 100% of the devices screen width when in landscape?

My code for creating the chart can be found at [Androidplot - X-Axis labels cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25780552/816754)

Comment: What happens if you run the above experiment on [the DemoApp's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidplot.demos&hl=en) bar chart activity?  Does it exhibit the same behavior?  It's working on my device.

Comment: No, the chart appears in landscape mode. What happens if you run my code at http://stackoverflow.com/q/25780552/816754 does it exhibit the incorrect behavior?

Comment: @Mark It appears in both mode here .But in Portrait mode it shrinks.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
 private View createBarGraph()
    {
        // initialize our XYPlot reference:
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) this.findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot1);

        // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
        Number[] series1Numbers = GenerateGraphValues();

        // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
        XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers), 
        SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the
                                                                                                // element index as the x value
                "Series1"); // Set the display title of the series

        BarFormatter series1Format = new BarFormatter(Color.rgb(51, 181, 229), Color.TRANSPARENT);
        PointLabelFormatter plf = new PointLabelFormatter();
        plf.getTextPaint().setTextSize(18);
        plf.getTextPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
        series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(plf);

        series1Format.setPointLabeler(new PointLabeler(){
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");

            public String getLabel(XYSeries series, int index)
            {

                // need to check for null
                if(series.getY(index) == null) return "";

                return df.format(series.getY(index));
            }
        });

        // add a new series' to the xyplot:
        plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

        // Y axis config
        plot.setRangeLabel("Values"); // label
        plot.setRangeBoundaries(0, 110, BoundaryMode.FIXED); // scale
        plot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 10); // steps
        plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setTextSize(26); // font size
        DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#0");
        plot.setRangeValueFormat(nf);

        // X Axs config
        plot.setDomainLabel("Indexes");
        plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 1);
         plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
        plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setTextSize(18);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginTop(20);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginBottom(15);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginLeft(15);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginRight(15);
//      plot.getLegendWidget().setHeight(14);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingLeft(15);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingRight(15);
//      plot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingBottom(20);
        // other config
        plot.getLegendWidget().setVisible(false); // hide legend
        plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // hide
                                                                                                                                                                // grid
                                                                                                                                                                // lines
        plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // hide
                                                                                                                                                                // grid
                                                                                                                                                                // lines
//      plot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingLeft(40); // give some padding
//      plot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingRight(40); // give some padding
        plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE); // background
                                                                                                                                                    // color
//      plot.getTitleWidget().setPaddingTop(10); // give some padding

        // set bar width
        BarRenderer<?> renderer = (BarRenderer<?>) plot.getRenderer(BarRenderer.class);
        renderer.setBarWidth(20);
        return plot;

    }
```